# Basic start with Visual Studio C# and SQL Compact (connect, select, insert)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to learn about C# with SQL CE so that my program can remember stuff.

I have created a database and can connect to it:

```
SqlCeConnection conn = 
         new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\dbJournal.sdf");
conn.Open();
```

And it connects right, I guess cause if I rename the `dbJournal.sdf` to something wrong it doesn't debug right.

Let's say I want to make a simple SELECT query.

```
(SELECT * FROM tblJournal)
```

How is that done?

What about a simple insert?

```
(INSERT TO tblJournal (column1, column2, column2) VALUES 
                                        (value1, value2, value3))
```

I'm used to PHP and MySQL (as you properly can see :o))

Comment: @gideon, thanks for editing. How can I make a code block? Best regards

Comment: You just need to select the text and press `Ctrl + k` It indents the text by 4 spaces which format it as a code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Chuck mentions EntityFramework which simplifies things and does all the work of writing the sql for you.

But there is a basic ADO.NET approach here which I will describe below.

The classes follow a standard pattern so to insert/read from sql server or other databases there are exact replica classes like `SqlConnection` or `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand` etc

This is the most barebones ado.net approach:

```
using( SqlCeConnection conn =
          new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\dbJournal.sdf") )
using( SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand() )
{
  conn.Open();
  //commands represent a query or a stored procedure       
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblJournal";
  using( SqlCeDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
  {
     //...read
  }
  conn.Close();
}
```

Then to read data :

```
while (rd.Read())
{//loop through the records one by one
     //0 gets the first columns data for this record
     //as an INT
     rd.GetInt32(0);
     //gets the second column as a string
     rd.GetString(1);
}
```

A nice and quicker way to read data is like this:

```
using( SqlCeDataAdapter adap = 
          new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblJournal", "your connection") )
{
  //the adapter will open and close the connection for you.
  DataTable dat = new DataTable();
  adap.Fill(dat);
}
```

This gets the entire data in one shot into a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) class.

To insert data :

```
SqlCeCommand cmdInsert = conn.CreateCommand();
cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT TO tblJournal (column1, column2, column2) 
                           VALUES (value1, value2, value3)";
cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: this is a great set of examples, but shouldn't there be a conn.Close(); somewhere?

Comment: @gideon Your connection is in a using block... doesn't this mean that connection will be automatically closed/disposed?

Comment: @Prokurors yep, the adapter in its inheritance chain inherits from `System.ComponentModel.Component` which is `IDisposable` so it sort of implies that it will do a cleanup. Also the adapter owns the connection because (from my example) the adapter takes a string and creates the connection. So my expectation would be that it would close the connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you just start learning that i will suggest you to use LINQ to make that queries.

Here is MSDN article showing features of LINQ.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx

Using LINQ it will be simple to do every query. For example, you can write your select query like this

```
from journal in TblJournal select journal
```

or just

```
context.TblJournal
```

Answer (score 1):

also  in order to improve performence , you better keep the conncection **open** all the time when working with SQL CE (as opposed to other standard sql databases)