# SQL Server compact

Tags: api, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to get data from api and insert them into a SQL Server `.sdf` database file, but I'm not sure how to do it especially that I'm using Windows forms on Visual Studio 2010

Can someone help me ?

Comment: If you want to insert data fast, you can use my SqlCeBulkCopy library

Answer (score 0):

This is a *very* broad question, however, at a very high level, you will need to open up a connection to the SQL Server Database and use a data access technology such as [ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/) or [EntityFramework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) to work with the objects in the database.

See the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818169/basic-start-with-visual-studio-c-sharp-and-sql-compact-connect-select-insert) thread for an example of working with ADO.NET.

Comment: i already made the connection to the database.sdf from winforms on Visual Studio 2010 and i prepared the Json data into variable items : var items = JsonConvert.Deserializeobject<IEnumerable<item>>(json_data) my question now is how to fill the json_data into my database.sdf ?

Comment: You will need to use a data access technology such as ADO.NET or EntityFramework to take your objects and populate the associated database tables. If you are already connecting the the database to retrieve data then you are already most of the way there.